# How to check if there is .plist saved to iCloud?

Tags: ios, swift, plist, icloud, icloud-documents

I have this app where in it will create a `.plist` file backup in *iCloud*. Upon testing in my test device (iPhone XR), it backups smoothly but when using different test devices such as *iPhone 6s plus*, *iPhone 5s* and *5*. It does not saved any data. It jumps automatically to alert controller **No data to save**. Please refer to the code below. Please educate me which part of the code I have missed that causes error. Please help me I been solving this for almost 2 weeks but still I haven't found any solution. Thank you

```
 //the storage location of the plist you want to save
    let strLibraryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.libraryDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    let strPlistPath = "\(strLibraryPath)/\(S_DIRECTORY_NAME)/\(S_PLIST_NAME)"
    localURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: strPlistPath)

    //judge if there is plist to save
    let aFileManager = FileManager.default
    if !aFileManager.fileExists(atPath: strPlistPath) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "保存するデータがありません \n (No data to save)", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    else {

    blYesNoAlert = true
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Confirmation", message: "バックアップを作成しますか？\n (Do you want to make a backup?)", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "いいえ", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { _ in
        //Cancel Action
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "はい",
                                  style: UIAlertAction.Style.default,
                                  handler: {(_: UIAlertAction!) in

                                    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.backupData), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```